# Can I disable a maven plugin from command line?

Tags: maven-3

Is there a way to execute a maven build from command line, but disable a configured plugin without changing the pom file?

*The reason for that is, that we have a number of given maven projects, which we develop together with a customer. In these projects a rpm plugin is configured, which does not run in our Windows environment. So I'd need a way to control the build in a way that it just ignores this build step without having to change the pom file (like using profiles, which I would use, if I were able to change it). Unfortunately the plugin does not have a skip property. 
The only other idea I had was faking the rpm command which is called in the plugin, but this didn't work.*